# Adding WMS and WFS layers from GEOSERVER in arcgis viewer for flex 3.0

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am interested in adding feature layers from geoserver in arcgis viewer for flex config file and consequently display them on the web map.IS that possible? If yes, could someone share how they did that and perform querying on the features (points and polygons)?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this. http://code.google.com/p/wfst-arcgis-viewer/
It works with 2.4. I am still troubleshooting the 2.5 graphics.

Answer (score 0):

arcgis viewer for flex 2.1 was not support wms but in 3.0 you can use wms. more [info](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapps/flexviewer/help/index.html#/Layer_tag/01m30000000p000000/)

```
Possible layer types are as follows:

tiled—Cached ArcGIS map service (9.3 or later).
dynamic—Non-cached ArcGIS map service (9.3 or later).
feature—Single layer in an ArcGIS map service or feature service (9.3 or later).
bing—Microsoft Bing layer (requires a Bing Maps key).
image—ArcGIS Server Image Service (9.3 or later).
arcims—ArcIMS Service (9.3 or later if using a Web Mercator projection).
osm—Basemap from OpenStreetMap.
wms—WMS service. [Added in version 2.2]
kml—KML feed.[Added in version 2.4]
```

for adding wms in your config file you should glance at "WMS as a service in Flex Viewer" [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2421&t=296172).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Hi Aragon, thanks for the response. I would like to overlay them and I have no idea of how to call them and parse them to the interface. Do you have a code sample of something that you have done previously? Appreciated.

Comment: check out this examples, you can see the code too [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html#//01nq00000010000000).

Answer (score 0):

try this one,
dowload the trunk source code.

http://code.google.com/p/wfst-arcgis-viewer/source/browse/

works with flexapi3.x and flexviewer 3.x