# Using GeoServer with ArcGIS Viewer for Flex

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer

I need to create a web GIS application using the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex graphical Appbuilder. Can I use it with GeoServer to publish my GIS data or is the viewer made exclusively for ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: I think this might help http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d93a120bffa941baa584bc49a97b85c2 and also maybe this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31070/adding-wms-and-wfs-layers-from-geoserver-in-arcgis-viewer-for-flex-3-0

Answer (score 1):

You can add your Geoserver layers as WMS layers to the ArcGIS Viewer for Flex, but to the best of my knowledge you may add it in the config.xml file, and not in Appbuilder. Please read more [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/flex-viewer/concepts/index.html#//01m300000052000000)